# Translation: ‘phone it in’

Tags: translation

Is there a **idiomatic** translation for ‘phone it in’ in Chinese?

Bolded what I'm looking for above, I'm not looking for things like `敷衍了事`, but something more **idiomatic**.

In case anyone is confused as to what phone it in means, the **Advanced English Dictionary** defines it as:

> *phone it in*
>
> (idiomatic) To fulfill a responsibility with a minimum effort rather than the appropriate level of effort.

Comment: Why do you think 敷衍了事 is not idiomatic?

Comment: 敷衍了事 is pretty idiomatic to me. Are you looking for something more *colloquial* or *slangy*?

Comment: I was hoping for something slightly less *direct*. 敷衍了事 just seems to be stating the facts like: *perfunctorily finish something*.

Comment: To me, "phone it in" is more particular than just any way of doing a sloppy job.  It means doing a job where you are supposed to have special ability -- like performing as a singer or musician, or teaching a class-- and you go through the motions without making any effort.  If I get hired to do lawn work and work slow and I sneak off every time I can to goof off out of the boss's sight, that is 敷衍了事 but would not be called phoning it in -- because you cannot "phone in" lawn work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“敷衍了事” is a right Chinese saying to describe your situation.

Besides,you can also say something like “搪塞”，“蒙混过关”…… related to this meaning.

Answer (score 0):

敷衍了事 is pretty idiomatic to me. An alternative which is a bit more formal is 敷衍塞責.